# Ionic tabbar not transparent on root page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile-development

I have made a transparent background tabbar on my ionic/angular app. I have the following code in my app.scss

```css
.tabbar {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
}
.tabs-ios .tabbar {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
}
.ion-tabs {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

It works fine when I test in the browser, but when I test with ionic view app, there is still a stock tabbar showing on the first page loaded by tabs page. Tabs are transparent on every other page, except the first one that is the "home" page.

Does anyone know why this is? Is this just a bug in the exceptionally unreliable Ionic View app or a problem I should be trying to fix?

Comment: status bar is a native cordova component you can change the color by adding in src/theme/variable.scss $toolbar-background:#44acba; or for transparent look here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-how-to-have-a-transparent-status-bar/50491

Comment: Thanks for the help, but adding $toolbar-background in variables.scss did not change anything. And the other one about the cordova component is for the status bar, I am having issues with the tabbar. And it works everywhere in my app except the first page that loads

Comment: Install the application on the android device, then you will be able to inspect it on chrome.

Comment: I have not yet purchased an android device for testing, but I will since I need to at some point. Will I get better tools than chrome browser view using ionic serve?